# LNK2019 unable to use GetStagedPackageOrigin()

Tags: visual-c++, lnk2019

I have been trying to use the [GetStagedPackageOrigin()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/appmodel/nf-appmodel-getstagedpackageorigin) to get the origin of a specific application in my system.

But my program is not compiling because of an unresolved external error.

Error   LNK2019 :   unresolved external symbol __imp__GetStagedPackageOrigin@8 referenced in function "void __cdecl check(wchar_t const *)" (?check@@YAXPB_W@Z)

Here is my code:

```
void check(__in PCWSTR fullName)
{ 
    PackageOrigin origin;
    LONG rc = GetStagedPackageOrigin(fullName, &origin);
    if (rc == ERROR_SUCCESS)
    {
        static PCWSTR originstring[] = {L"Unknown",L"Unsigned",L"Inbox",L"Store",L"DeveloperUnsigned",L"DeveloperSigned",L"LineOfBusiness" };
        PCWSTR str = originstring[origin];
        wcout << str << endl;
    }
}
```

Why does this error keep coming and is there any way to resolve that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I used dumpbin command in the visual studio command prompt and that function was not being exported from kernel32.dll. The function was not present in the dll in the first place.
I think that is why the error occured.